# Symfony2, Use QueryBuilder with KnpPaginatorBundle

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, knpmenubundle

I'm using KnpPaginatorBundle and I'm using QueryBuilder in Repository to select data. I was obliged to put parameters **sort** and **direction** in variables **$sort** and **$direction** and pass them to the Query to be able to do and **orderBy**.

This code works but I'd like to show it to you and and have your opinions if it's a good way to do this with KnpPaginatorBundle or there is another better way provided by knpPaginatorBundle.

Can I pass those parameters directly to knp_paginator not in the queryBuilder ?

**`Action`**

```
public function listAction($page, Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $paginator  = $this->get('knp_paginator');


    if($request->query->get('sort') and $request->query->get('direction')) {
        $sort = $request->query->get('sort') ;
        $direction = $request->query->get('direction');
    }
    else{
        $sort = 'id'; // set default sort
        $direction = 'asc';  // set default direction
    }   

    // pass those two variables to query
    $listTravels = $em->getRepository('ProjectTravelBundle:Travel')->getListTravelsFrontend($sort, $direction);

    $pagination = $paginator->paginate(
        $listTravels,
        $this->get('request')->query->get('page', $page)/*page number*/,
        10/*limit per page*/
    );

    return $this->render('ProjectFrontendBundle:Frontend:list.html.twig',array(
        'pagination' => $pagination
    ));
}
```

**TravelRepository:**

```
public function getListTravelsFrontend($sort, $direction) // parameters $sort, $direction
{

    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('t')
        ->leftJoin('t.image', 'i')
        ->addSelect('i')
        ->leftJoin('t.agence', 'a')
        ->addSelect('a')
        ->Where('t.enabled = 1')
        ->orderBy('t.'.$sort, $direction); // orderBy with those parameters

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();

}
```

Comment: If you pass the Query instead of the ResultSet to knp_paginator, then it will automatically handle the sorting for you.

Comment: Can you explain me more please ?

Comment: Don't perform query by `getResult()`, pass to paginator Query object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@phpisuber01 is right, his answer helps me understand. Unfortunately, official KnpPaginator site does not give example for QueryBuilder but does mention /* query NOT result */ in https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle.

Here is the example code for QueryBuilder:

First in Repository:

```
/*
 * GiftDataRepository.php (in Repository/... directory)
 * return all records in table GiftData.
 */
public function getLatestRecords()
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('q')->select('q');
    // getQuery() returns query NOT result.
    return $qb->getQuery();
}
```

Second in Controller:

```
 /*
  * TabulaRepository.php (in Controller/... directory)
  * return pagination object within template.
  */
 public function giftsDataShowAction(Request $request, $format)
{
    $em             = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $giftsdataquery = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:GiftData')->getLatestRecords();

    $paginator = $this->get('knp_paginator');
    /* page number 1, limit per page 5 */
    $pagination = $paginator->paginate($giftsdataquery, $request->query->getInt('page', 1), 5);

    // parameters to template
    return $this->render('data/data_gifts.html.twig', array('pagination' => $pagination));
}
```

Third in View:

```
<div class="count">Total of: {{ pagination.getTotalItemCount }}</div>
<table class="table table-responsive table-striped">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        {# sorting of properties based on query components #}
        <th class="hidden-xs">{{ knp_pagination_sortable(pagination, 'Id', 'q.id') }}</th>
        <th {% if pagination.isSorted('q.circumstances') %} class="sorted"{% endif %}>{{ knp_pagination_sortable(pagination, 'Circumstances', 'q.circumstances') }}</th>
        <th class="hidden-xs">{{ knp_pagination_sortable(pagination, 'Date Of Report', 'q.dateOfReport') }}</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    {% for row in pagination %}
        <tr {% if loop.index is odd %}class="color"{% endif %}>
            <td id="col" class="hidden-xs">{{ row.id }}</td>
            <td id="col">{{ row.circumstances }}</td>
            <td id="col" class="hidden-xs">{{ row.dateOfReport }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

That is it.

Answer (score 0):

knp_paginator, itself work on sort and direction keyword from url, you don't have to pass them.
see doc - https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle

$listTravels, it will return all results from database - what if you have too many records.

```
$pagination = $paginator->paginate()
```

only fetch limited results, based on your limit.

You can directly use `$paginator  = $this->get('knp_paginator');` in repository class after passing `$this->container` as argument or any other method and can use

```
$paginator  = $this->container->get('knp_paginator');
```